# Using results from pymongo

Tags: python, flask, flask-pymongo

I have an api using flask and flask-pymongo Im trying to deal with a login function and using passlib try and check if a password hash matches

Im getting a 500 server error when making a call to the endpoint

My code is as follows:

```py
def login():
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']

    # Find user record by email
    user = db.user.find_one({'email': email})

    # If user not found return message
    if not user:
        return jsonify(message='We cannot find you, please sign up')

    # If user found check password and return token
    hashed = user.password
    test = pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, hashed)
    # Returns on success
    if test:
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=email)
        return jsonify(message='Login Successful', access_token=access_token), 202
    else:
        return jsonify(message='Password incorrect'), 403
```

the error is here

```
TypeError: The view function for 'login' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2021 20:24:37] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

as I Am new to Python I'm wondering if Im using the return correctly here

```py
hashed = user.password
```

Comment: The flask app should dump a stack trace. We would need to see that.

Answer (score 0):

So after much playing and trying to log the return I have seemed to have fixed it and the return needs to use square brackets

So my hashed line needs to be as follows

```py
hashed = user['password']
```

And that was my error.

All working now!